# Buttons in Java taking on values of the button pressed before

Tags: java, swing, button

I am working on a project for class where a piece of code is displayed as an image and buttons are hidden where the errors are in the code. The idea being that the user can then click on the area of code where they think the error is and the button becomes visible- I have set it to be translucent red so the user can still the error underneath. What is happening in the code is the buttons are working, but when I hit another button the button takes on the view through the last button. For example the first button is over error 'j k' and when clicked it becomes red and can still see the error. However when hit the next button where the error is 'i+j' the first button then changes to display 'i+j' taking on the second buttons error. As the error is embedded in an image I am not quite sure how this is happening. Any help would be very welcome.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tutorial1Test extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane; 

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JButton one = new JButton();
JButton two = new JButton();
JButton three = new JButton();
JButton four = new JButton();
JButton five = new JButton();
JButton six = new JButton();
JButton seven = new JButton();
JButton eight = new JButton();
JButton nine = new JButton();

int clickCount = 0;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 * 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Tutorial1Test frame = new Tutorial1Test();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Tutorial1Test() throws IOException {


    //create, format and locate jframe
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//exit program when framed closed
    setBounds(300, 75, 800, 600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/gui/Tutorial1TestImage.png"));
    background.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
    contentPane.add(background);

    JLabel count1 = new JLabel("count");
    count1.setBounds(100,110,45,20);
    //count1.setText(Integer.toString(clickCount));
    contentPane.add(count1);

    one = new JButton();
    one.setBounds(100,110, 45, 20);
    hideButton(one);
    contentPane.add(one);

    one.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {   

                showButton(one);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    two = new JButton();
    two.setBounds(100, 215, 45, 20);
    hideButton(two);
    contentPane.add(two);

    two.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {                               
                showButton(two);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    three = new JButton();
    three.setBounds(95, 240, 150, 20);
    hideButton(three);
    contentPane.add(three);

    three.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {                               
                showButton(three);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    four = new JButton();
    four.setBounds(275, 265, 45, 20);
    hideButton(four);
    contentPane.add(four);

    four.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {   

                showButton(four);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    five = new JButton();
    five.setBounds(320, 365, 45, 20);
    hideButton(five);
    contentPane.add(five);

    five.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {   

                showButton(five);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    six = new JButton();
    six.setBounds(35, 395, 45, 20);
    hideButton(six);
    contentPane.add(six);

    six.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {   

                showButton(six);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    seven = new JButton();
    seven.setBounds(100, 440, 45, 20);
    hideButton(seven);
    contentPane.add(seven);

    seven.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {   

                showButton(seven);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    eight = new JButton("");
    eight.setBounds(100, 520, 45, 20);
    hideButton(eight);
    contentPane.add(eight);

    eight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {   

                showButton(eight);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    nine = new JButton("");
    nine.setBounds(550, 545, 45, 20);
    hideButton(nine);
    contentPane.add(nine);

    nine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {   

                showButton(nine);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

//after you create your panel
contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {  
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {  
         if (evt.getClickCount() >=12) {

         //close window

         }  
         else {  
            //display number of clicks
            clickCount =  evt.getClickCount();

             }  
         }  
 });
}
public static void hideButton(JButton button){

    //change button settings so not visible on opening
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setOpaque(false);

}
public static void showButton(JButton button){

    //change button back to visible but transparent with colour to highlight error
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(true);
    button.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0,25)); 


}


}
```

[image]

Comment: In all of that code, at no point do you show us where the button obtains a value? As it stands, they're just empty buttons. Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: they are supposed to be empty, I only need the button to change to a translucent colour. I don't want any text

Comment: is that the problem, do I need to set them to an empty string. At the minute they get their background from the showButton() method at end

Answer (score 1):

I would do things differently:

- I would give my program an array of Rectangles or `ArrayList<Rectangle>` and fill the collection with a list of the "active" rectangles on the image.
- I would give my program a Rectangle variable, say called *pressedRect* that is initially set to null.
- I would have my gui class extend JPanel and give it a MouseListener.
- In this listener's `mousePressed(...)` method, I would iterate through the Rectangles in the array or collection to see if any of them have been pressed.
- If pressed, I would set the pressedRect variable to the Rectangle identified in the Mouselistener.
- I would draw the image in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel.
- In the same `paintComponent(...)` method, I'd check if pressedRect is null and if not, I'd fill it in using `Graphics2D#fill(...)` method. You could use a translucent color for this such as `new Color(0, 80, 0, 80)`.